# Git pull and overwrite

Tags: git

I'm new to working with other people with git.

I have a repo on github that my friend made changes to. I okayed them and merged the pull request.

How do I pull the code onto my system, and overwrite everything? I am still on the master branch in my local system.

Running git pull:

```
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

How do I checkout master if I am already on master?

Comment: _"How do I checkout master if I am already on master?"_ you don't? I'm assuming that you don't have a tracking branch set up. What if you try `git pull origin master`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox the master on my local system is behind the one on github

Comment: `git pull origin master` worked. Thanks

Comment: Right. That's why we `git pull`.

Comment: So, the git output hint was your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would try running `git pull origin master` instead of `git pull`.

Comment: Hi Dean, it would be nice if you explained *why* the OP should try this command. This way they can learn not just how to fix their problem, but also how Git works, and your answer may be helpful for other users in the future. Check out this article: https://stackoverflow.com/tour